# Add zero in number in Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a formula in Google Sheets to find the number of the week of a date. The desired result would be a concatenation of S + the number of the week (with a space between the two). If the number of the week is less than 10, I would like an extra 0 in this data.

Here are the different results desired according to the different cases:

```
01/01/2023 → S 52
02/01/2023 → S 01
27/08/2023 → S 09
```

After many attempts, I still cannot incorporate the 0 when the week number is less than 10. Could you please help me?

Here is my formula (assuming a date is in A1):

```
="S "&(SI(NO.SEMAINE(A1)-1<10);"0"&NO.SEMAINE(A1)-1;NO.SEMAINE(A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try:

```
="S "&TEXT(WEEKNUM(A1;21);"00")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `TEXT()` function. Try-

```
="S + " & TEXT(WEEKNUM(A1);"00")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Harun, but i have problems with your formula. It's work to sunday at sunday. I would like to define a week to monday at sunday. For exemple, if i try your formula for these dates, i don't have a "good" answer : 03/01/2022 i obtain S 02 but i would like S 01, same for 31/12/2022 i obtain S53 but i would like S52. And if i try this : =SI(F4<>"";("S " & TEXTE(NO.SEMAINE(O4)-1;"00"));""), I obtain S 0 sometimes.